# Fatal Error: namespaced class not found in self-defined path

Tags: php

I am trying to use PHP's traits feature and namespacing to organize my project's codes and files.

But I do not know why I get this

> Fatal error: Class 'ModernPHP\News' not found in E:\www\modernphp\test.php on line 11.

There are my files in the same directory. I just have a directory modernphp; the three files are beyond this directory.

Am I misusing namespaces? Or is it something else?

## mysql.trait.php

```
<?php
namespace ModernPHP;

trait db_connect
{

    protected $host;
    protected $user;
    protected $pwd;
    protected $db;

    protected $connect;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pwd = $pwd;
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pwd);
        mysqli_select_db($this->connect, $this->db);
    }

    public function query($table, $arr_fields = array(), $order_by = false)
    {

        $sql = 'SElECT * FROM {$table}';

        return mysqli_query($this->connect, $sql);
    }
}
```

## News.php

```
<?php
namespace ModernPHP\News;

    class News
    {

        use mysql;

        /*
        public function __construct()
        {
            //$db = new m
        }
        */

        public function latestNews()
        {

        }

    }
```

## test.php

```
<?php

namespace ModernPHP;

    use ModernPHP\News;

    class test {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $news_object = new News('localhost', 'root', '', 'invo');

            print_r($news_object);
        }
    }

    $test = new Test;
```

--- Add at Jan.06.2016 ---

```
class ComposerAutoloaderInita3585bdd4dd862cdaf5a9a8f6faaa488
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInita3585bdd4dd862cdaf5a9a8f6faaa488', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
```

Comment: Where did you `include` files?

Comment: namespace does not need to include files.

Comment: @user39291 that's incorrect; you still need to autoload or explicitly include the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see. I mistake the namespace's feature.

Answer (score 3):

You defined your class `News` in `namespace ModernPHP\News` (see top line of News.php). That means the class, with namespace, is `ModernPHP\News\News`, not `ModernPHP\News`.

You either meant to define `News` in `namespace ModernPHP` (replace the `namespace` line in News.php with `namespace ModernPHP;`) or you need to `use ModernPHP\News\News;` in your definition of `ModernPHP`.

Also, you need an autoloader or explicit `include`/`require` statements to load your class and trait files. You can't simply do `new News(...)` if you haven't loaded the News.php file or told PHP how to do so.

Comment: I have change it as your answer, but it doesn't make any effect.

Comment: @user39291 which change did you make?

Comment: I change namespace ModernPHP\News; in New.php file to namespace ModernPHP;

Comment: @user39291 I didn't actually ask you this; I just assumed it: are you using `include`/`require` or an autoloader? You do need an autoloader (recommended) or explicit `include`/`require` statements to make the class and trait definitions available.

Comment: I am going to check it how to write a autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you also have the subfolders for your namespaces
e.g.

```
namespace ModernPHP\News;
```

you need a folder ModernPHP with a subfolder News, in this subfolder is your class News. You can then use the class with:

```
use ModernPHP\News\News;
```

Comment: I remove News in the line: namespace ModernPHP\News, but I still get the  same error.